# span count up with a condition javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am working in node.js with the leap motion, and I want a counter to count up +1 inside the span every time a users (numberOfFingers ==5).-- this being the condition, how do I go about this? I know that I need to write a function and an if statement, .count is the class of the span. A point in the right direction anyone? I've seen a lot of counters using setInterval and setTimeout but this is not what I'm after!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

var c =  canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

//Set up the controller
var controller = new Leap.Controller();
controller.on( 'frame' , function(frame){
  c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  var numberOfFingers = frame.fingers.length;
  c.font = "200px Arial";
  c.textAlign = 'center';
  c.textBaseline = 'middle';
  c.fillText( numberOfFingers , width/2 , height/2 );


});


controller.connect();
```

Jade:

```
span#count 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  But I think something like this is what you're looking for?

```
if (numberOfFingers == 5) {
    var start = parseInt(document.getElementById('span-id').innerHTML);
    start++;
    doucment.getElementById('span-id').innerHTML = start;
}
```

Every time the number of fingers is 5.  It will find the HTML of the span, convert it to an int, increment it by one, and finally append the result to the span.

**Edit:**

If you're wanting to do something on every 5th count then you can use modulus `%`.

```
var some_counter = 0;    
someFuncThatIncrementsSomeCounter();
if (some_counter % 5 == 0) {
    // do something
};
```

If you only want to increment when fingers are 5, then you can use my original example:

```
if (numberOfFingers == 5) { counter++; };
```

Comment: sorry about the vagueness! This didn't work, I'm looking for something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/65TMM/ but instead of the score counting up on click, it counts up when numberOfFingers == 5, shall i post the code I have at the moment? if your free to help?

Comment: Please see the above (thanks for taking the time btw)! I only want the span to increment when fingers are 5! I want it to count up each time the condition is being met!

Comment: @plimbs  If numberOfFingers is an integer then you can just ask it if it is equal to 5 `if (numberOfFingers == 5)` and within that if block you can use my original answer to change the html to increment by 1.